# Performing an AJAX call from JS in asp.net MVC without Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing an app that will be used on an old WInCE devices where IE Embedded doesn't support Jquery, which is why I can use it. So, my question is, what is the way to perform an AJAX call from within a js file.

Code:

html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "SomeAction", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myId" }))
{
  input field 1: <input type="text" name="somename1"><br>
}
```

What I need to do is call a validate routine and return a string when the user clicks enter on the `somename1` input field.

Normally, this would be done with Jquery, so how do I do it without only utilizing what the MVC asp has to offer (again, the ajax might not work at all on the old browser, but I would like to give it a shot and avoid refreshing the whole page).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get a XMLHttp Object using:

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    // to create XMLHttpRequest object in non-Microsoft browsers
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (exp1) {
            try {
                // to create XMLHttpRequest object in older versions
                // of Internet Explorer
                xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (exp2) {
                xmlHttpReq = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttpReq;
}
```

Then do this (Just an example for downloading a file ajax request)

```
function myFunction(){
    var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler_download_file(xmlHttpRequest,file_indicator);
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "/wasa-app/DownloadServlet?pmuId="+pmuID+"&dlDate=" + formatted_date+"&check_flag=1"+"&file_indicator="+file_indicator, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
}

function getReadyStateHandler_download_file(xmlHttpRequest, fileIndicator) {
    return function() {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
                populateSchedule();
                var resp = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
                if (resp == ""){
                    document.getElementById("save_" + fileIndicator).disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("save_" + fileIndicator).disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
                }

            } else {
                alert("HTTP error -- " + xmlHttpRequest.status + ": " + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
```